# Error al conectar a bbdd desde php

Tags: php, mariadb

Tengo un archivo **.php** que desde el me conecto a una bbdd remota de un servidor que tengo. Nunca llega hacer la conexión, y creo que es culpa del código. Ya que la configuración remota esta activada, el usuario sql esta configurado para que se puede conectar desde cualquier **IP**.

**La bddd es MariaDB**

**Desde el mysql workbench me puedo conectar sin ningun problema, desde código php me da error**

Version de PHP: 7.3.11

Version BBDD: 10.3.17-MariaDB

**Código**

```
$user = "remote";
$password = "1234";
$server = "192.168.1.17";
$bbdd = "login";
$table_users = "login";


$connect =  mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password);

$db = mysqli_select_db($connect, $bbdd);


if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) ){
  $query = "SELECT * from " + $table_users + " WHERE user = '" + $_POST['username'] + "'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

  // No esta en un while porque solo devolvera una linea de la bbdd, ya que el username es unico
  $info = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  if ($info['user'] !== $_POST['username'] &&  $info['passw'] !== $_POST['password']) {
    echo 0;
  }else {
    echo 1;
  }
}else{
 echo 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error obtienes?

Comment: Por consola ninguno eso es lo raro. Pero hago un if(! $connect) y entra el if

Comment: hazle un **`var_dump($db);`** y comentanos que obtienes como resultado

Comment: @Aprendiz perdon la tardanza, el **var_dump($db);** me devuelve bool(true), despues he probado **var_dump($query)** y devuelve int(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error está al momento de declarar la variable `$query`

```
$query = "SELECT * from " + $table_users + " WHERE user = '" + $_POST['username'] + "'";
```

En `PHP` la [concatenación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php) se realiza con un punto `.`, cambialo por esto:

```
$query = "SELECT * from " . $table_users . " WHERE user = '" . $_POST['username'] . "'";
```